# Zipkin server as a eureka client

Tags: java, spring-boot, zipkin

Finding the best way in order to register my Zipkin Server on Eureka Discovery Server, seems that custom servers are possible but not supported by the community so the most correct way is modify the source code.

The process done was:

1. Clone repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin
cd zipkin
```

2. Add Eureka Client dependency on zipkin-server module (same versions than my other microservices)

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

3. Enable eureka client on ZipkinServer.java

```
@EnableEurekaClient
```

4. Add configuration needed properties in zipkin-server.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: shared
  application:
    name: ZIPKIN-SERVICE

armeria:
  enableMetrics: false

eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

5. Compile and run

```
./mvnw -DskipTests --also-make -pl zipkin-server clean install
java -jar ./zipkin-server/target/zipkin-server-*exec.jar
```

I tryied to use @EnableDiscoveryClient instead of @EnableEurekaClient and try some other configurations on zipkin-server.yml but always server isn't registered on eureka without showing any error message. Here the repository: https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/zipkin/tree/feature/discoveryServiceClient

What can I do register Zipkin server on Eureka?

Thanks,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

Added next dependencies

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>2021.0.5</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Update Spring Boot Version

```
<spring-boot.version>2.7.0</spring-boot.version>
```

Restore zipkin-server.yml and add next properties in zipkin-server-shared.yml:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```